# Can I create a ViewHelper for a javascript-block?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers, raty

I'm cleaning up my code of my Rails-app. I'm using the `Raty-gem` for my rating system. To render a `#average_rating` I'm using a script-block (picked this up in some tutorial) in the specific views. But since I'm using the `#average_rating` in over 6 different views, I was hoping that I could do this more efficient. I already tried to use a HelperMethod for it, but i guess that it doesn't accept 'javascript'.

**Script-block:**

```
<script>
$('#average_rating').raty({
    path: '',
    readOnly: true,
    score: <%= @project.average_rating %>
});
</script>
```

What is the cleanest way of doing this in Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is cleaner way of defining a JavaScript block using `content_for` helper method provided by rails. You can define a code snippet inside a named `content_for` block and can be used anywhere in your views. 
e.g

```
<% content_for :rating_code do %>
  $('#average_rating').raty({
    path: '',
    readOnly: true,
    score: <%= @project.average_rating %>
  });
<% end %>
```

See documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for

Comment: Okay, looks simple. But where do I place this block of code: in a helper-method? (it seems like it contains view-code) Or somewhere else?

Comment: You can define content for tag in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` file and initialize it in any of the views. The code will be only generated in which page you have yield the code like this `<%= yield(:code_tag_name) %>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data to pass to the JavaScript and you want to keep your js code in js files, you can use [the Gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon)